# Java transferring variables from a super class to the sub class

Tags: java, constructor, this, extends

In java i have a class A which extends class B

I want to assign all of the contents from class B to class A
thing is i want to do it from inside class A now this seems reasonable easy to do just transfer all of the variables.

This is the hard part. I didn't make class B it's a part of android.widget
In c++ you would just take in class b and then assign to *this and cast it.

How would i go about doing this in java?

To further clarify it's a relativelayout i need to copy all the contents of a relativelayout into a class that extends relative layout

```
class something extends other
{
public something(other a){
 //transfer all of the other class into something
 this=(something)a;  // obviously doesn't work
 //*this doesn't exist?
 //too many variables to transfer manually
}
}
```

Thanks so much for all the help. Really appreciate it!!!

Comment: when you extend a particular class you automatically inherit all the properties of that class..isnt it?

Comment: I think he has an object of class A and an object of class B and want to copy class B's fields values to the object of class A.

Comment: What is the exact type of object that `other a` is referring to ? If it is of class `something` then your code would surely work..

Comment: That's pretty much what i want Jean Waghetti

Comment: If you know the name of all those variables then you can use the reflection API to copy those values..

Comment: It's a relativeLayout class B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the code given below . It is using `java.lang.reflect` package to extract out all the fields from super class and assigning the obtained value to the child class variables.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
class Super
{
    public int a ;
    public String name;
    Super(){}
    Super(int a, String name)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
class Child extends Super 
{
    public Child(Super other)
    {
        try{
        Class clazz = Super.class;
        Field[] fields = clazz.getFields();//Gives all declared public fields and inherited public fields of Super class
        for ( Field field : fields )
        {
            Class type = field.getType();
            Object obj = field.get(other);
            this.getClass().getField(field.getName()).set(this,obj);
        }
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        Super ss = new Super(19,"Michael");
        Child ch = new Child(ss);
        System.out.println("ch.a="+ch.a+" , ch.name="+ch.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will have to give this a sit down and see if it works. I did a work around that works in my case but doesn't actually answer the question. But i'll have to look at this later. Thanks seems to be the real deal tho :D

Comment: this won't on the private fields right? might become a problem. if android.widget.RelativeLayout has any really really important private fields instead of protected? anyone knows?

Comment: @Lpc_dark: The private fields of super class is never accessible to the child class.Let only super class to take care of its private fields. This is in accordance with the overriding rule..

Comment: Thank you so much. Real life Hero is what you are

Answer (score 0):

All the variable and function of parent class(not private) is direct access in child class.You don't need to assign any thing in child Class.You can direct access.

Comment: As I commented in the question, I think he has an object of class A and an object of class B and want to copy class B's fields values to the object of class A.

Comment: Yes that is what i want. I need to object b fields to copy to the object A since object A extends B

Answer (score 0):

This will **not** work:

`Something something = (Something) other.clone();`

if the **true runtime type** of other is `Other`.

Instead you have to create a copy constructor, or instantiate `other` as an instance of `Something` and then clone it.

Comment: The object is an android.widget.RelativeLayout I won't have access of all of it's stuff to copy it manually